# Can you suggest some challenging calculus questions?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I am a calculus 2 student, just passing high school. I would really appreciate it if you can suggest some cool challenging questions for a high school student with solutions or hints too!

Comment: I don't think this is the right forum to ask, but regardless, a great source of non-trivial problems, there is the artofproblemsolving website, and for calculus, it has this book: https://artofproblemsolving.com/store/item/calculus-ebook?gtmlist=Bookstore_OnlineBooks_Side.

Comment: These look pretty fun: https://brilliant.org/community/problems/popular/hard/calculus/

Comment: David dong, I am pretty new to this platform, so, can you elaborate why is it wrong to ask it here and where should I ask it? And also, thanks for the link, to both David and K defaoite.

Answer (score -1):

Here are two that I've seen on this network.

**Problem 1.** Show that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\big(\frac{1}{4n+1}-\frac{1}{4n}\big)=\frac{1}{8}(\pi-8+6\ln 2)
$$

**Problem 2.** Evaluate the indefinite integral
$$
\int e^{\sin x}(x\cos x-\sec x\tan x)dx
$$

Comment: Why a downvote? Are these not challenging enough for someone just out of calc 2?

Comment: Two downvotes now? If someone wants to provide constructive feedback I will happily edit/delete

Comment: Ah I see the question is being downvoted and marked as not right for this forum. So perhaps that's the problem? I can delete my answer, but perhaps I will wait to see if any anonymous downvoters have the courage to provide specific feedback. (I don't bite!)

Comment: Actually I just saw this, I just forgot about this question (Sorry). And I do like these problems. I don't know who the hell down voted this, but sure as hell, I just upvoted this.  Let me just try these...

Comment: Okay, I did the second problem in under 3 minutes, but it took rest of the hour to figure out the first one, and I still don't know what the hell should I do. Still, I will try and when I would give up, I will let you know and I hope you can provide me a satisfying solution

Comment: No, I am unable to solve the first problem, can ya send me the solution, please?

Comment: Here is a hint: viewing $n$ as fixed, write $\frac{1}{4n+1}-\frac{1}{4n}$ as an integral $\int_0^1 f_n(x) dx$ where $f_n(x)$ is a power function (depending on $n$). Then move the infinite sum inside the integral and you will have something of the form $\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x) dx$. If you choose $f_n(x)$ correctly you can use the formula for a geometric series viewing $x$ as a fixed number between $0$ and $1$. You will then have an integral $\int_0^1 F(x) dx$ for some absolute function $F(x)$....

Comment: But just in case, the answer is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3738262/how-to-prove-sum-limits-n-1-infty-left-frac14n1-frac14n-rig/3738319#3738319